# select query in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have database design like this...

```
   dated       ref       weight  no.  address

21-03-2013  ABCD/EDFG     1234   A45   A1 
20-03-2013  ABCD/EDFG     789    A56   A2
25-03-2013  ABCD/EDFG     6981   A99   A5 
23-03-2013  GAJHS/ASDH     72    A82   GV
```

what i want here in the query result is something like this....
 search on the basis of **no.**
 but then, it has to see if the **ref** of that row exists more times and if it exists then it has to add the weight of all such rows keeping in mind **dated** of all such records should be less than the dated of selected **no.**.

example -

```
no. = A56
three rows exist with same ref(ABCD/EDFG)
but dated of A56 is lower among all so results should be 

     ref ------ weight --------  no. -------- address
ABCD/EDFG ------ 789 ----------- A56 -------- A2
```

but in the case of no. = A99 results should be like this -

```
ref ----------- weight --------  no. -------- address
ABCD/EDFG --- (789+6981+1234) ----------- A99 -------- A5 

as dated of A99 is greater than other two records.
```

please help me in this query.

Comment: Well, you could just use a nested query to do this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: this is what i have tried but this does not seems good ....

    select sum(nett_weight) from dpy_weighment_delivery_dtls where order_ref = (select order_ref from dpy_weighment_delivery_dtls where gate_pass_no = 'J9272') and weighed_date......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
   ref, 
   sum(weight) over (partition by ref order by dated) as weight,
   no,
   address
from
   ...
```